# tkinter variable trace method

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, trace

I am trying to activate callback function as the user type in to the tkinter entry box. According to [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm),

> You can use the trace method to attach “observer” callbacks to the
>   variable. The callback is called whenever the contents change:

So i tired this,

```
import Tkinter as tk
window2=tk.Tk()
anf_frame1=tk.Frame(window2,bg='white',relief='groove',bd=0,width=1190,height=175)
anf_frame1.place(x=10,y=50)

def myfunction(*args):
        print 'pass'
stringvar1 = tk.StringVar(anf_frame1)
stringvar1.trace("w", myfunction)
anf_fault_entry=tk.Entry(anf_frame1,width=35,font=('calibri',(14)),bg='white',textvariable=stringvar1)
anf_fault_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=(5,5))

window2.mainloop()
```

The above script works fine.But when i copy this to my main script, it doesn't print out the 'pass' anymore. It doesn't give me any error either.

I have confirmed that there is no other variable name `stringvar1` and same function name `myfunction`. And there is no typo error as i just used copy paste function.

I am now puzzled why it doesn't work when i copy it to my main script.

Just for info, my main script is working as it should before i copy the trace callback and after. My main script has tkinter window with a few labels and entry boxes which should not affect the above operation. What is causing the problem? Did i miss something?

**--- EDIT ---**

```
def Entrybox_002():
    def myfunction(*args):
            print 'pass'

    window2=tk.Toplevel(root)
    md1.Drag_Window(window2, nf_sizex, nf_sizey, nf_posx, nf_posy, nf_title, nf_titlesize,nf_level)    
    ''' New Entry labels & Dropdowns'''
    #Frame to hold labels
    anf_frame1=tk.Frame(window2,bg='white',relief='groove',bd=0,width=1190,height=175)
    anf_frame1.place(x=10,y=50)
    anf_frame2=tk.Frame(window2,bg='#CCF1FF',relief='groove',bd=0,width=700,height=85)
    anf_frame2.place(x=50,y=140)

    label_list=['JCN','Fault','System','Sub-System','Status','Faultcode']
    for i in range (6):
        tk.Label(anf_frame1,text=label_list[i],font=('calibri',(16)),bg='white').grid(row=1,column=i,padx=(40,40),pady=(5,5))

    anf_jcn_number=tk.Label(anf_frame1,text=Calculate_linenumber(),font=('calibri',(16)),bg='white',fg='blue')
    anf_jcn_number.grid(row=2,column=0)


    stringvar1 = tk.StringVar(anf_frame1)    
    stringvar1.trace("w", myfunction)
    anf_fault_entry=tk.Entry(anf_frame1,width=35,font=('calibri',(14)),bg='white',textvariable=stringvar1) #<------------------------ENTRY BOX THAT I AM TRYING TO TRACE
    anf_fault_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=(5,5))

    anf_system_menu = md1.MyOptionMenu(anf_frame1, 'Select System', anf_system_choices,Subsytem_display)
    anf_system_menu.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=(5,5))
    (anf_system_menu.var).trace("w",myfunction)

    anf_status_menu = md1.MyOptionMenu(anf_frame1, 'Select Status', anf_status_choices,Subsytem_display)
    anf_status_menu.grid(row=2,column=4,padx=(5,5))
    (anf_status_menu.var).trace("w",myfunction) 


    anf_faultcode_menu1 = md1.MyOptionMenu(anf_frame1, 'When fault found?', anf_faultcode_1,Operational_effect)
    anf_faultcode_menu1.grid(row=2,column=5,padx=(5,5))  
    (anf_faultcode_menu1.var).trace("w",myfunction) 

    anf_date_button=tk.Button(anf_frame2,image=images.adf_date_chooser,text='Date',compound='left',font=('calibri',(12),'italic'),bg='white',command=Create_calendar)
    anf_date_button.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=(15,15),pady=(5,5))

    anf_ownership=tk.Label(anf_frame2,text='Reported by',font=('calibri',(14),'italic'),bg='#CCF1FF')
    anf_ownership.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=(15,15),pady=(5,5))

    anf_date_label=tk.Label(anf_frame2,text=today_date,font=('calibri',(14),'italic'),bg='#CCF1FF',fg='blue')
    anf_date_label.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=(15,15),pady=(5,5))

    anf_button1=tk.Button(window2,text='Submit',relief='groove',bd=1,font=('calibri',(12)),bg='green',padx=10,pady=3,command=Submit_Newfault)
    anf_button1.place(x=1100,y=175)
    anf_button1.config(state='normal',bg='grey')
```

This is the function that create the entry box (`anf_fault_entry`) i was asking about. It is on a top level window with other several widgets. I tried to trace the other option menus (for example `anf_system_menu` and `anf_subsystem_menu`) using the same function i used for entry box but it seems working fine for those option menu. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Your main script had mainloop() call? and now two mainloop() calls?

Comment: Without seeing the non-functioning code it's impossible for us to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: @falsetru there is only 1 mainloop() call as it should. What more puzzling is that i added 1 new optionmenu and trace the "stringvar" of that optionmenu with the same funtion and it works fine as it should.. what could have possibly gone wrong?

Comment: Can you post your main code somewhere? I can't guess any other cause.

Comment: @falsetru added the potion of code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringvar1` is garbage collected (deleted) when Entrybox_002 function return.

Workaround:

```
stringvar1 = window2.stringvar1 = tk.StringVar(value='asdf')
```

I recommend you code Entrybox_002 as class, and stringvar1 as instance attribute to keep reference.

Comment: Thanks you so much. that fixed the problem..i have been spending last 2 hrs troubleshooting that problem. i am a beginner so i have no idea about the garbage collector.. i have to read up more about it.