# Tkinter Entry/Text widget problem when I use bind function

Tags: python, events, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm new to Tkinter, I want to print Entry's contents while I'm typing.
Here's my code I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *


def get_(e):
    print(entry.get())

root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.bind("<KeyPress>", get_)

mainloop()
```

But it seems not "synchronous"(when I type "123" in, output only is "12" and so on)

The following code works properly, but I don't know why:

```
from tkinter import *


def get_(e):
    print(entry.get())

root = Tk()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

root.bind("<KeyPress>", get_)
## or this: entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", get_)
## or this: entry.bind_all("<KeyPress>", get_)

mainloop()
```

is there some weird rule I don't know about? Any and all help would be wonderful, thanks in advance!

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, this has all the information you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for your comment. I read your answer and code. So what bind tag like "Entry" does is insert some characters into the widget. Am I right?

Comment: @Darcy: ***"print Entry's contents while I'm typing"***: You want [tkinter-variable-trace-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131826/tkinter-variable-trace-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: `entry.bind("<KeyPress>"` seems not *"synchronous"* (when I type `"123"` in output only is `"12"` and so on ...), while `root.bind("<KeyPress>"` works.

The event `entry.bind("<KeyPress>", ...` get fired **before** the value in `tk.Entry` is updated. This explains why the output is allways **one** char behind.

The event `root.bind("<KeyPress>", ...` get fired **after** the value in `tk.Entry` is updated. This explains why this is working.

**Alternatives**:

- Use the `"<KeyRelease>"` event
- [tkinter-variable-trace-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131826/tkinter-variable-trace-method)

---

**Reference**:

- [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)
- [trace method to attach “observer” callbacks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)